# Calculating a rotation matrix: error and properties

Tags: physics, rotations

Given an axis $u=\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt 3/3, \sqrt 3 /3, \sqrt 3 /3
\end{bmatrix}$ and an angle $\phi =\frac{2\pi}{3}$ I want to calculate the related rotation matrix:

Well given Rodriguez’s formula:

\begin{align*}Rot(u,\phi)&=I\cos\phi+uu^T(1-\cos\phi)+\hat u \sin\phi\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos\phi & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cos\phi
\end{pmatrix}+(1-cos\phi)+\hat u\sin\phi
\end{align*}
Yet,

\begin{align*}
\hat u
&=\begin{bmatrix}
\hat u_1\\
u_2\\ u_3
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -u_3 & u_2\\
u_3 & 0 & -u_1\\
-u_2 & u_1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\sqrt 3/3 & \sqrt 3/3\\
\sqrt 3/3 & 0 & -\sqrt 3/3\\
-\sqrt 3/3 & \sqrt 3/3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Therfore:

\begin{align*}
Rot(u,\phi)&=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos\phi & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cos\phi
\end{pmatrix}+3(1-cos\phi)+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\sqrt 3/3 & \sqrt 3/3\\
\sqrt 3/3 & 0 & -\sqrt 3/3\\
-\sqrt 3/3 & \sqrt 3/3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\sin\phi\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\sqrt 3/3 & \sqrt 3/3\\
\sqrt 3/3 & 0 & -\sqrt 3/3\\
-\sqrt 3/3 & \sqrt 3/3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\sin\phi\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1/2 & 1/2\\
1/2 & 1 & -1/2\\
-1/2 & 1/2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

It seems to be false and even violate the translation matrix properties (which I don't remember)

**Therefore can you help me know which properties does I violate  and what should be the actual rotation matrix?**

I've heard that there is another way than Roderiguez's formula to calculate $Rot(u,\phi)$, do yu know which?

Comment: You lost the $uu^T$ from the second term right off the bat.

Comment: And $\cos(2*\pi/3)=-0.5$, not 1

Comment: @Andrei Yes! Thank you both! I corrected the first line. But in the end it leads to the same matrix isn't it?

Comment: $uu^T= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \end{array} \right)$